# Laravel relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Trying to figure what table I need to make this relationship to work...

I'd like the user to mark a post as favorite and save it so when he log back in, he can view all his favorite posts.

So I have User and Post models and their relationships of course.

User hasMany Post, Post belongTo User

Do I need to add Favorite model and add fav_id to both User and Post models ?
Or maybe adding pivot table?

Comment: Is the User / Post relationship pertaining to which User created which Post? Or which post(s) are a User's favorite Posts?

Comment: I've updated the post and added my relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a favorite is defined as a simple relationship between users and posts, you don't need a model for it. However, you do want a pivot table, call it something like `favorites`. It would contain `id`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

Then in your user model:

```
public function favoritePosts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'favorites');
}
```

And in the post model:

```
public function favoritedBy()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'favorites');
}
```

So now, for any given user, you can do `$user->favoritePosts` to get an array of posts that user has "favorited".

And from a post object, you can do `$post->favoritedBy`, to get an array of users that have favorited that post.

I haven't tested this but that seems like that would work off the top of my head.